# Difference between lists created with struct and list library c++

Tags: c++

I learned about lists in school.

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    int data;
};
```

I saw that there is a library with lists;

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list <data_type> variable_name;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any difference between them ?

Comment: Your `Node` is similar to a part of a [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)`<int>`

Comment: Fun fact: `std::list` doesn't have to be a doubly linked list, but the way it has been specified by the C++ Standard makes the doubly linked list implementation almost certain. You have to be solving a very interesting problem (or be utterly mad) to use an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are that `std::list`

- is a templated class, which can take any type as value, not only `int`
- keeps the `Node` structure interned, and `head` and `tail` pointers will be managed by that class
- it is implemented as a *double-linked list*, where the nodes have a pointer to the next and to the previous node, the mode exact equivalent from the standard library would be `std::forward_list`
- iterators can be used with standard library algorithms, whereas that's not possible out of the box using the simple `struct Node`

There are probably more differences, but these are the main ones.

In case you're asking in terms of efficiency, or overhead, there's no difference from the hand rolled linked list.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between your `Node` class and the nodes used in `std::list<T>` is primarily that your `Node` class do not contain a pointer to previous node and it's not generic.

The `std::list<T>` class follow all the standard conventions such as `value_type`, `size_type` etc. And have all sorts of neat constructors, member functions, iterators and so forth.

A good reason to use `std::list<T>` over your hand-rolled list is that you will be able to use it with your favorite `<algorithm>` without any fuss